# How to disable "Screen is Pinned" dialog android from kiosk mode

Tags: android, react-native

iam developing screenlock app for android using a **React Native** and a little annoyed with the **screen pinned** dialog that always appears, is there a way to just get rid of it? so what I really want is no dialogue interaction at all with the user

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEELi.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

If you're calling [`startLockTask()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startLockTask()) and your device isn't set up as a [dedicated device](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode) with your app whitelisted, then no you can't prevent it:

> Otherwise, the current task will be launched into screen pinning mode. In this case, the system will prompt the user with a dialog requesting permission to use this mode. The user can exit at any time through instructions shown on the request dialog.

The dialog is there to help users understand what's happening, give permission for the app to take over their screen, and know how to get out of it later. It's baked into Android by design, so malicious apps can't cause problems - it's just a limitation you have to deal with, unless you're working with a *dedicated device* (which can be set up to give apps more control and users less)

Have you thought about [immersive mode](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/immersive) instead, where you hide the nav bar? The user can get out of that too by swiping to reveal the controls, but it's less intrusive. There's no way to automatically lock the user's screen with no interaction though